# Permission denied module importation with Spacepy

Tags: python, permissions, anaconda, python-import

I need Spacepy package. I installed it carefully following [these](https://pythonhosted.org/SpacePy/install_linux.html) instructions with no particular problem. At the end of the installation, I did:

```
python
>>> import spacepy
```

And it worked just fine. Later on I tried to run a script which uses spacepy and I got an import error with this package. Then I did:

```
python
>>> import spacepy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "spacepy/__init__.py", line 329, in <module>
    _read_config(rcfile)
  File "spacepy/__init__.py", line 297, in _read_config
    _write_defaults(rcfile, defaults)
  File "spacepy/__init__.py", line 200, in _write_defaults
    f = open(rcfile, 'r+t') #Avoid race condition, open for read and write
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/arnaud/.spacepy/spacepy.rc'
>>>
```

I tried:

```
cd ~/.spacepy
chmod +rwx spacepy.rc
```

But it didn't change anything. I also tried to run python with sudo, and it does not work as well, although I have a different error:

```
sudo python
>>> import spacepy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacepy/__init__.py", line 131, in <module>
    from . import datamodel
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacepy/datamodel.py", line 178, in <module>
    from . import toolbox
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacepy/toolbox/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from spacepy import time as spt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacepy/time.py", line 101, in <module>
    import dateutil.parser as dup
ImportError: No module named dateutil.parser
```

In addition, when running python with sudo, I cannot load all the other packages (numpy, scipy, etc...). I installed python 2.7 with anaconda.

Do you know something I could try ?

I did the exact same procedure on another computer and it worked with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Change spacepy.rc file permissions was indeed the good solution, but I did not apply it to all users with 'a' flag. Doing:

```
cd ~/.spacepy
chmod a+rwx spacepy.rc
```

Solved the problem